Understanding the relationship between values in an LTspice transformer
I am designing an LTspice transformer based on these values.:


8.8 W, 12 V AC, @500m A
Vout (no load) = 14.38 V @ Vin = 122.5 V
Vout (@480 mA) = 11.60 V


Datasheet for reference.
What I am struggling with is understanding how to properly simulate this in LTspice. Currently, my setup is as follows:

Whenever I modify the R1 value to simulate an actual load, I get some very low current values (expected), but trying to find a balance between these, has felt like guessing so far, and I'm wondering if there is a more methodical way to achieve similar characteristics to the specs I put above, using formulas/calculations rather than just changing values until I achieve similar results.

I have a few questions: 1) 8.8W, 12VAC, @500mA Where's that 8.8W coming from? 12Vac and 0.5A bring you 6 VA (not Watts unless the load is pure resistance). 2) Where did you get a coupling coefficient of 0.95? Do you know the actual leakage? 3) Without the DC resistance info, you can't simulate the voltage drop with loading. Do you know the DC resistances of both windings?

@RohatKılıç

This is the relevant datasheet, listing 8.8W. Could be because RMS? Sorry for the confusion. 2. I have been modifying the coupling coefficient to adjust the current and voltage to my spec (the datasheet doesn't have any information on coupling so it has been difficult). 3. Right now, the DC resistance of each inductor is 1m Ohm. Again, this is just speculation and not based on the datasheet.


Apparently, the 8.8W rating is the power drawn by the primary when the secondary is loaded with 0.5 A, hence the 80% efficiency. As for the DC resistances, I don't think both the primary and secondary have ~1 mOhm DC resistance because, judging from the numbers in the datasheet, the primary inductance is about 5~6 H so 1 mOhm doesn't look like a realistic number. However, it might be possible to extract a rough number from the datasheet.

Thank you for your help @RohatKılıç. May I ask, how were you able to extract 5~6H from the datasheet? I will try to extract other values from the datasheet, now that I know it is possible.

The excitation current is the magnetising (magnetisation) current drawn by the primary magnetising inductance. Of course, there is also the DC resistance in series, and possibly a leakage as well, but ignoring them for now, you can simply calculate the primary mag reactance which is $X_L=2\pi f L_p$, from 120 Vac and 55 mA. Then you can extract the primary inductance.

Thank you @RohatKılıç, that actually makes perfect sense now. I do wonder though how I could get the coupling coefficient from the datasheet or based on calculations, any tips?

You can't get the coupling coefficient instantly but you can measure the leakage and calculate the coupling factor. This requires either an LCR meter or a signal source and a scope. You can google the details. If you don't have the chance to measure, you can assume it 1.00 to start with. DC resistances matter as well because you have a secondary voltage that drops with loading. Sec-side is easy: unloaded vs loaded difference will tell you about the sec winding's DC resistance. Or you can measure both winding's DC resistances with a current-limited power source.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
